# Is there a Regex suggester

Tags: regex

I use regexes just often enough to be dangerous.  I sometimes am hacking with grep and have a finite set of possible strings to match and will need to come up with a regex that will accept these but not another finite set of strings.  Is there a tool that will suggest some regexes that can solve my problem?  I know the general case is hard, but often I have finite enumerated lists and do not need the "best" regex, just a good enough one.

For example: 
accept_list={'bog', 'fog', 'frog'}
reject_list ={'ogle', 'bogle', 'ogre'}

could be solved by 'og$', where I am assuming that $ indicates the end of the string. 
I am not picky about the type; POSIX or PERL flavors are fine.
Is this a hard problem in the finite case?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if an automated regex generator, if one were to exist, just came up with `'^(bog|fog|frog)$'` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the finite case this is very easy since regex includes alternation (or):

```
grep '^\(bog\|fog\|frog\)$'
```

For example accepts only the strings `bog`, `fog`, and `frog`, while rejecting all other strings.

So, indeed, it is very easy to come up with a regular expression that accepts any finite language.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there are regex suggesters but i use a very good live regex matcher. You can find it at the link bellow:

> http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

P.S. it makes regexing so much faster :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an easy problem to solve but there is a tool to help you with that called [RegexMagic](http://www.regexmagic.com/) which is a Regular Expression Generator

> RegexMagic makes creating regular expressions easier than ever. While
>   other regex tools such as RegexBuddy merely make it easier to work
>   with regular expressions, with RegexMagic you don't have to deal with
>   the regular expression syntax at all. RegexMagic generates complete
>   regular expressions to your specifications.
>
> First, you provide RegexMagic with some samples of the text you want
>   your regular expression to match. RegexMagic can automatically detect
>   what sort of pattern your text looks like. Numbers, dates, and email
>   addresses are just a few examples of the wide range of patterns that
>   RegexMagic supports. By marking different parts of your samples, you
>   can create regular expressions that combine multiple patterns to match
>   exactly what you want. RegexMagic's patterns provide many options, so
>   you can make your regular expression as loose or as strict as you
>   want.

Answer (score 0):

I use RegexHero all the time. If you enter this Target String:

> bog frog fog ogle bogle ogre

and this regex:

> \b[a-z]*og\b

you'll see that it matches the words you want and excludes the others.

http://regexhero.net/tester/